# How to create 5 and 4 (for mobile) equal column on Boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanted to create 5 equal column on bootstrap for my responsive design with container-fluid. I have managed to do it. But I need one of those columns to disappear on lower resolutions. (Which I have already did as well) So on the mobile view I want to separate those 4 columns into two rows equally. However, my current code is failing to do it so. It gets separated into 2 rows but on the first row there are 3 equal column and on the second row there is only one column which is equal to those 3.

This is my current Bootstrap code;

```
      <div class="container-fluid content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-xs-6">
             <div class="stats">
               <div class="big">111</div>
               <div class="small">COLUMN 1</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col col-xs-6">
             <div class="stats">
               <div class="big">222</div>
               <div class="small">COLUMN 2</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col d-none d-md-block">
             <div class="stats">
               <div class="big">333</div>
               <div class="small">COLUMN 3 (DISAPPEARS ON LOW RES)</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col col-xs-6">
             <div class="stats">
               <div class="big">444</div>
               <div class="small">COLUMN 4</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col col-xs-6">
             <div class="stats">
               <div class="big">555</div>
               <div class="small">COLUMN 5</div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-xs-*-` no longer exists in Bootstrap 4 beta. Use `col-sm` for equal width columns on sm and up, and `col-6` for 50% width columns on mobile (xs)

https://www.codeply.com/go/W46IKaZhdR

```
<div class="container-fluid content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-6">
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="big">111</div>
                <div class="small">COLUMN 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-6">
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="big">222</div>
                <div class="small">COLUMN 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="big">333</div>
                <div class="small">COLUMN 3 (DISAPPEARS ON LOW RES)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-6">
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="big">444</div>
                <div class="small">COLUMN 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-6">
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="big">555</div>
                <div class="small">COLUMN 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```